# Is there a java library for image?

Tags: java, image, image-processing, resize

I am new to image processing in java .
I was given a task to re-size and scale images image of a web site

Is there a simple Library that will do this task?
a library where i have to download a jar - added to my project ?
I prefer not to be forced to install codecs and files to the windows.

I need the library to support only the basic functions

```
Lib.cropImage();
Lib.resizImage();
Lib.scaleImage()
```

I already found a library called `JAI` but I can't find the jar to download it.
Am I missing something ?

Comment: Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/244164/resize-an-image-in-java-any-open-source-library)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the standard [Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html) class part of Java libraries.
Scaling images should be fairly easy by using [Image.getScaledInstance(int width, int height, int hints)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html#getScaledInstance%28int,%20int,%20int%29)

Comment: thanks for the answer
but when i use this function iam unable to save it to the Disc


Image  img = null;
img = ImageIO.read(new File("D:/files/save/Penguins_1321871576590.jpg"));
      img.getScaledInstance(50, 50, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH); 


how can i save it to the hard drive since the Image has no method to do that ?
am I forced to convert it to buffered Image and then save it Using ImageIO ? or there is easier way ?

Comment: Hi, glad it helped. That is a different question, please accept this answer if it resolved the original question and post a new one about saving a scaled image into disk :). Please post the link here as well so that I can follow up with it :)

Answer (score 3):

For cropping, use [`BufferedImage.getSubimage()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getSubimage%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495566/java-image-crop) StackOverflow Q&A for more details). For resizing, use [`Graphics.drawImage()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage%28java.awt.Image,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.image.ImageObserver%29) (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/244177/649852) StackOverflow answer for more details). And for scaling, use [`Image.getScaledInstance()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html#getScaledInstance%28int,%20int,%20int%29).

Other options are:

- [`JMagick`](http://www.jmagick.org/) (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3967809/649852) StackOverflow answer).
- [ImageJ](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/)
- Use [`ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) to execute [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) commands.

Answer (score 1):

The Java2D library ought to be sufficient enough.

Answer (score 0):

For image processing puroses I would recommend a package from the [following list](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/).

In your case JAI would do the job, and you can download it [here.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/current-142188.html)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [imageJ](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/) which boasts to be world's fastest pure Java image processing program