# How to save JPanel as JPEG with its components

Tags: java, swing

I need to save a chessboard as a jpeg file. I know how to save a java component into JPEG. But my problem is that I use JButtons as cells and when I try to save the whole chessboard, only the panel is saved. Does anybody know **how to save a JComponent WITH ITS CHILD COMPNENTS into JPEG (png etc.)** Thank you in advance.

Comment: why not use the `Prnt Scrn` key of the keyboard and save the image as you want, if it can give you what you want :)

Comment: You can use `paintAll()`, where you'd normally use `paintComponent()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Screen Image](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/13/screen-image/). It will allow you to create an image of any component in the frame. If you choose to make an image of a panel all the child components are included in the image.

Answer (score 2):

You can print a `Component` (such as `JPanel`) to any `Graphics` object. So, why not use the `Graphics` object of a `BufferedImage` and write it to disk.

```java
void takePicture(JPanel panel) {
    BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(panel.getWidth(), panel.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    panel.print(img.getGraphics()); // or: panel.printAll(...);
    try {
        ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", new File("panel.jpg"));
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This makes this `JPanel`

```
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.add(new JButton("Hello"));
    panel.add(new JButton("World"));
```

Look like this:

[image]

*updated based on comments, many thanks to @MadProgrammer*

Comment: Using `paint` has issues if the component is not already displayable.  It also uses double buffering which can cause issues with the rendering process.  It would normally be better to use `print` or `printAll` in this case...I might also be better to use the components preferred size instead of it's actual size, depending on when the component is begin painted, just saying ;)

Comment: Actually, it doesn't (`paint` vs `print`) painting and un-displayed component can cause exceptions under some systems because `paint` expects to be attached to a native peer ;)

Comment: Also, because of the way the double buffering works on some systems, it may not even produce a result...so no, I would say it doesn't always do what the OP wants ;)

Comment: I've had issues with this approach on Windows 7 and Mac OS.  Regardless, `print` and `printAll` are designed to do exactly what the OP is asking.  Just because something works, doesn't make it right ;)

Comment: Will it work if I have a scroll on my panel? I mean that the invisible area must be saved as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use Robot class to create a screen capture of your screen.

Use this tutorial for help:
[Screen Capture using Robot class](http://mrbool.com/capture-your-screen-using-java/24324)

Now for your chessboard, clip the image by calling subImage method of BufferedImage class.

[Here's the link on clipping BufferedImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495566/java-image-crop?answertab=active#tab-top)

You can get Dimensions of you JPanel by calling getX(), getY(), getWidth() and getHeight() methods which you can pass into subImage method.
Manipulate the passing value by adding/substracting some value to get desired results.